# Run React Native code while application is closed

Tags: android, react-native

### Problem

I have been trying to create a React Native application used to catch phone calls and send the numbers to an API. I have created a working native module for catching the phone calls in Java. I have also managed to send an event to my JavaScript code and managed to catch this event and log the number through console.log in JavaScript.

Now my problem is that i need the application to work even if the application is closed (in background). I have not been able to find any way to wake the react native code with a Java module or to run the Javascript without starting the application.

---

### Code

This is my BroadcastReciver:

```
package com.wavyassist;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;


import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

/** 
 * Created by Erik on 2016-04-06.
 */
public class CallCatcher extends BroadcastReceiver {

private CallCatcherModule module;

public CallCatcher (){
    this.module = CallCatcherModule.getInstance();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
    {
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Call from:" +incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        module.sendCallEvent(incomingNumber);
    }
        else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
                                    ||     intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(     TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
        {
            // This code will execute when the call is disconnected
            Toast.makeText(context, "Detected call hangup event", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Module:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.Map;

public class CallCatcherModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    private ReactContext reactContext;
    private static CallCatcherModule instance;

    public static CallCatcherModule getInstance(ReactApplicationContext     reactContext){
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new CallCatcherModule(reactContext);
        }
        return instance;
    } 

    private CallCatcherModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
    } 

    @Override
    public String getName(){
        return "CallCatcherModule";
    } 

    public static CallCatcherModule getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }  

    public void sendCallEvent(String incomingNumber){
        WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
        params.putString("Number", incomingNumber);
        sendEvent(this.reactContext ,"CallRecevied", params);
    }


    private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext,
                            String eventName,
                            @Nullable WritableMap params) {
        reactContext
            .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
            .emit(eventName, params);
        Log.d("CallCatcherModule", "Event Emitted");
    }
}
```

These classes will always send the number when call is catched. To receive the event in javascript I am currently using this working example. (this code only works if i restart the entire application.)

```
"use strict";


import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Navigator,
  TextInput,
  DeviceEventEmitter
} from 'react-native';

var emitter;

class RegDone extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCall = this.handleCall.bind(this);
    this.changeListenerState = this.changeListenerState.bind(this);
    this.state = {test: ''};
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    console.log('RecivingCall: Starting Listener');
    emitter = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('CallRecevied', this.handleCall);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    console.log('RecivingCall: Stoping Listener')
    emitter.remove();
    this.setState({text: ''});
  }

  handleCall(Event){
    console.log('RecivingCall: Call Recevied! Number: ' + Event.Number);
    this.setState({test:  Event.Number});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text >
            {this.state.test}
          </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#aaaaaa',
    padding: 20,
  },
});


module.exports = RegDone;
```

---

### What I have tried

I have tried to write the JS code in a separate class that is not a view. This I failed with. There were no way I could contact the methods in the new class and ended up writing the code in a view class again.

I have also tried to start and stop the DeviceEventEmitter on button press but this simply did nothing.(not sure why!)

---

### Summary

The problem seems to be that the JavaScript is only available when the application is up and running and the specific view containing the JS code is on display.

If anyone have any information regarding how you run React native JS code while the application is closed or if you know a way to start the application up when an event is triggered. I would very much appreciate the information.

Comment: are you not getting this exception when trying to send the events?
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Trying to invoke JS before CatalystInstance has been set!

Comment: I can't see that  i do. The "sending event" part seems to work flawlessly. I have trouble starting and stoping the JS event listener on command and cant receive events if the application is closed.